# Preferential removal of partial duplicates in a dataframe, dependant upon multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

While removing rows that are duplicates in one particular column, is it possible to preferentially retain one of the duplicate rows based upon the second and third columns?

Consider the following example:

```
# Example dataframe.
df <- data.frame(col.1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                 col.2 = c('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a'),
                 col.3 = c('b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b'))
# Output
col.1 col.2 col.3
    1     a     b
    1     b     c
    1     b     a
    2     a     b
    2     b     a
    2     c     b
    3     a     c
    3     a     b
```

I would like to remove rows that are duplicates in `col.1`, while preferentially retaining rows that have `col.2 == 'b'`, and `col.3 == 'c'`. A match in both `col.2` and `col.3` is preferred the most, while a single match in `col.2` is preferred over a single match in `col.3`, and a match in just one column is preferred over no match at all. For duplicate rows with no matches, any one of the duplicate rows may be retained.

In the case of the example given, the resultant data frame would look like this:

```
# Output.
col.1 col.2 col.3
    1     b     c
    2     b     a 
    3     a     c
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `group_by` the `col.1` and `col.3` while preferentially retaining the duplicates that have `col.2 == 'b'`. Then you take the output of this and `group_by` just `col.1` while preferentially retaining the duplicates that have `col.3 == 'c'`, you end up with the desired result. This also follows the desired logic, if the preferred values are changed.

```
df %>%
  group_by(col.1, col.3) %>%
  slice(match('b', col.2, nomatch = 1)) %>%
  group_by(col.1) %>%
  slice(match('c', col.3, nomatch = 1))


# Output:
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   col.1 [3]
  col.1 col.2 col.3
  <dbl> <fct> <fct>
1     1 b     c    
2     2 b     a    
3     3 a     c
```

Answer (score 1):

We group by 'col.1', `filter` rows where 'col.2' is 'b' or 'col.3' is 'c', then `filter` out the `duplicated` rows based on the 'col.2' and 'col.3' values

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   group_by(col.1) %>% 
   filter(col.2 == 'b'| col.3 == 'c') %>%
   ungroup %>%
   filter(!duplicated(.[-1], fromLast = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  col.1 col.2 col.3
#  <dbl> <fct> <fct>
#1     1 b     c    
#2     2 b     a    
#3     3 a     c
```

Comment: This has the desired output for the particular example given above, but if I were to change the preferences to `col.2 == 'a'` and `col.3 == 'a'` then it doesn't work. It returns two rows that have `col.1 == 3`, when it should only return one row per distinct `col.1` value.